# How to print the rest of a string after a space

Tags: c++

I am trying to print a name,last name and thirdName but I don't know how to do it within a single string. I know how to print the string until there's space, but I don't know how to print the string after the space.To be more clear,this code shows the string until the space

```
string name = "Firstname Secondname ThirdName";
    string GetFirstName;
    for(int i=0; i<name.length();i++){
        if(name[i] == ' '){
            break;
        }
        else{
            GetFirstName = GetFirstName + name[i];
        }
    }
    cout << GetFirstName;
```

In this example I print `"Firstname"` What I am asking is how I print `"Secondname"` AND `"ThirdName"`

Comment: Do you need to achieve this from first principles?  Why not use any of the standard approaches such as `std::string::find` with `std::string::substr`, or `std::getline` with `std::istringstream`, or `std::regex`, to name a few.

Comment: @paddy How would getline help

Comment: Because `getline` can accept any delimiter character of your choosing.

Comment: @paddy I'd prefer not to use librarys or functions just how to do it in a loop but if no one answers then your answer is good

Comment: @Nope Keep in mind that the standard library isn't an external library, it comes standard in C++. Also, it appears you're using `std::string` anyway, so why not another standard library function?

Comment: All you need to do is remember the position in the string where you encountered the space.  Instead of making `i` local to the loop, just define it outside and use while-loops to read each string.  It's poor style, but I suspect that doesn't matter to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the code like the following:

```
string name = "Firstname Secondname ThirdName";
string GetName;
for(int i=0; i<name.length();i++){
    if(name[i] == ' '){
        cout<<GetName; // printing the name till the space
        GetName = ""; // clearing the variable, to capture the next part
    }
    else{
        GetName = GetName + name[i]; // adding to the GetName
    }
}
cout << GetFirstName;
```

Hope this helps, THanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that none of the suggestions in comments works for you. So the fix for your code would be:
the break line makes your code exit from for loop and it doesn't process the rest of string. so change the break to continue:

```
string name = "Firstname Secondname ThirdName";
string GetFirstName;
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
{
    if (name[i] == ' ')
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        GetFirstName = GetFirstName + name[i];
    }
}
cout << GetFirstName;
```

if you need to store second and third name in different strings, the code would be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

I write a code to print the separate name based on the user input. If you 
choose 1 - it prints the first name
choose 2 - the second name and
choose 3 - third name

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name = "Firstname Secondname ThirdName";
    string GetFirstName, GetSecondName, GetThirdName;
    int count=0, n;   // count used for counting the space
    cout<<"Enter number 1 for first, 2 for second and 3 for third name: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<name.length();i++){

        if(n==1){
            if(name[i] == ' '){
            break;
            }
            else{
                GetFirstName = GetFirstName + name[i];
            }
        }
        else if(n==2){
            if(name[i] == ' '){
                count++;
                i++;                //to remove extra space
            }
            if(count==1){
                GetSecondName = GetSecondName + name[i];
            }
            if(count==2){
                    break;
                }
        }

        else if(n==3){
            if(name[i] == ' '){
                count++;
                i++;            //to remove extra space
            }
            if(count==2){
                GetThirdName = GetThirdName + name[i];
            }
            if(count==3){
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << GetFirstName<<endl;
    cout << GetSecondName<<endl;
    cout << GetThirdName<<endl;
}
```

Comment: That is really inofficent